# Unable to check for availability of any element removing hardcoded delay

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a script in vba in association with selenium to initiate a search in some torrent site. My script is doing fine but the problem is I had to use `hardcoded delay` within my script to make it successful. What I wish to do now is check for the availability of desired element using some loop or any of that sort by kicking out hardcoded delay from my script. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

This is my attempt so far (working one):

```
Sub SearchItem()

    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "https://torrentz2.eu/"

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")  ''I wish to shake this hardcoded delay off
        .FindElementByCss("#thesearchbox").SendKeys ("Udemy")
        .FindElementByCss("#thesearchbutton").Click
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Selenium Type Library
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590274/selenium-how-to-wait-until-page-is-completely-loaded. Looks like there are few methods you can try there.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Wildry for your comment. The thing is there are options for `explicit wait` when it comes to work with selenium in combination with other languages but in case of `vba` I doubt there is any. At least i could not find anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have found the solution already. There is [the link](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/69) leading to github where `Florent B.` has provided an excellent solution as to how the script should wait until the desired element is available.

This is how the script should be:

```
Sub SearchItem()

    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "https://torrentz2.eu/"
        .FindElementByCss("#thesearchbox", timeout:=10000).SendKeys "Udemy"  ''wait for the element upto 10 seconds
        .FindElementByCss("#thesearchbutton").Click
    End With
End Sub
```