# Click the "Log in" button using Excel VBA-Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've written the following code to open a webpage in Chrome (note, you may have to click through a "Captcha" robot test page). I can successfully enter my username and password, but I am unable to click the yellow <kbd>**Log in**</kbd> button.

```
Sub Annuity_Value_Selenium()
' Note: added reference to Selenium Type Library

Dim WDriver As New WebDriver
    
' Open Chrome and navigate to login page
    WDriver.Start "Chrome", ""
    WDriver.Get "https://www.prudential.com/login/"
 
' Maximize the window
    WDriver.Window.Maximize
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
      
    WDriver.Get "https://www.prudential.com/login/"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    
' log-in   
    WDriver.FindElementById("user").SendKeys ("abcd")
    WDriver.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("efgh")

    WDriver.FindElementById("loginLink").Click
'
    Do stuff
'
End sub
```

I have tried the following additional approaches as well, but I am still unsuccessful in clicking the <kbd>**Log in**</kbd> button:

```
WDriver.FindElementByCss("a[class='btn evo-button   ']").Click
```

and

```
WDriver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(text(), 'Log in')]").click
```

I know that the webpage is loaded and active because the macro correctly inserts the username and password.

Even without using a username or password, you'll know that you were successful in clicking the button if you get an error message back saying `Error: Please provide a username`.  How can I programmatically click the <kbd>**Log in**</kbd> button?

Comment: Have you made sure the web page has enough time to load? Maybe play around with `TimeValue("0:00:10")`, etc.? Typically I use `DoEvents` with my web scraping, but I don't know how that works with Selenium.

Comment: @dwirony Yes, I've tested it, it has adequate time to load.  Thanks for the thought.

Answer (score 1):

`we.FindElementByXPath("//evo-link-button[@type='secondary']").Click`

This might work for you. It gives me the following error message -

**Run-time error 11**

**ElementNotVisibleError**

**element not interactable**

The error message suggests that the XPath is valid and has found the element that I am aiming for but will not click it until other conditions are met, for example a valid username has been entered which I don't have.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it doesn't work.  You shouldn't get any error messages other than on the web page where it should say Error: Please provide a username and Error: Please provide a password right below those two input boxes after a successful click.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, I don't have experience with Selenium WebDriver specifically in VBA and was a bit surprised to find that it doesn't support explicit waits where you can specify a condition (an element to be clickable or visible, etc...) before proceeding with an action. The usages of Explicit Wait are [documented here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/). Perhaps the long term solution is to move to a supported language in WebDriver. However based on [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50238062/unable-to-check-for-availability-of-any-element-removing-hardcoded-delay)  the author of SeleniumBasic did enhance find method with an implicit timeout, maybe it's worth a try...

```
WDriver.FindElementByCss("a[class='btn evo-button   ']", timeout:=10000).Click
```

Comment: as I mentioned above, I don't think it's a "wait" problem.  The macro successfully enters my username and pw, it just cant click the Log in button.  I'm guessing that I'm just not clicking on the right line of html.