# How to handle Dynamic rows after clicking 'Add Row"

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to automate a web-page to fill form. 
I have an issue where i need to keep entering data according to excel sheet.

So, if i have 2 rows of data in excel i need to click "Add Row" button in the web-page and then fill the form accordingly.
And if i have 3 rows in excel, then i need to click twice on "Add Row" button web-page and then fill it.

The approach here (what i have done) is to click the "Add Row" button firstly according to number provided by the user in any cell beforehand.
And then fill out the form.

**But this does not seem to work.**

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G8").Value = 2 Then
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G8").Value = 3 Then
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G8").Value = 4 Then
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click

ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G8").Value = 5 Then
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").Click

End If

bot.FindElementById("export-HS-code").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("B11")
bot.FindElementById("raw-material-description-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("C11")
bot.FindElementById("raw-material-quantity-unit-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("D11")
bot.FindElementByName("raw_material_unit[1]").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("E11")
bot.FindElementById("raw-material-unit-cif-value-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("F11")
bot.FindElementById("raw-material-total-cif-value-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G11")
bot.FindElementByName("raw_country_id[1]").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("H11")
bot.FindElementById("bill-invoice-no-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("I11")
bot.FindElementById("bill-invoice-date-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("J11")
bot.FindElementById("supplier-details-1").SendKeys ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("K11")
```

I know this is not a good way of doing it, because what if i need to click the "Add Row" 10-20 times, this code will not be an efficient way.

[image: Image for Help]

**Thus asking for help here.**
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: for i = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Annexure").Range("G8").Value: bot.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='add btn-add-raw-materials action']//i[@class='fa fa-plus-circle']").click Assuming 1 is for add 1 more row. Or see if there is a repeat syntax as with sendkeys. You may also need some wait condition to be sure row added. Or use a custom wait clickable js injection via executeScript you can async add (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989219/6241235))

Comment: Also, check if you can simply do this with a POST request to server.

Comment: Creating an "import Excel file" function in that app would be much much quicker... and probably less development time, too.  Look into Apache POI. (NPOI for C#)