# Detect an element in webpage using selenium with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, automation, whatsapp

I am new to selenium and I am using it with VBA for WhatsApp automation.
I want to ask that supposed there are two elements 'A' and 'B' on webpage but not simultaneously present.

So how I can write a code where if I detect element 'A' code should exit the sub or if I detect Element 'B' it's should continue with code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989219/6241235 If A Is Nothing Then Exit Sub etc Remember On Error wrapper.