# How to wait for an ajax Element by using VBA and Selenium

Tags: ajax, vba, selenium

Is it possible to wait for a slow ajax element?
In 95% the following code works fine, but in 5 % the Element needs more time to load and the Code will stop by showing a Error-Message.

```
driver.Wait 2000
driver.FindElementsByXPath("//button").Last.Click
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver (VBA): Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variation in the old wait system used with Internet Explorer.

```
Do While SeDriver.FindElementsByXPath("//button").Last.IsDisplayed = False
    DoEvents
Loop
```

As needed, you can switch "IsDisplayed" with "IsPresent".