# Wait until web application loaded in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

In the following code I am trying to navigate to use the web application "WhatsApp"

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

Const NO_JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
Const JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

Set bot = New ChromeDriver
Set ws = ActiveSheet
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

With bot
    .SetProfile JS_PROFILE, True
    .Get "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & arr(1)
```

The code works fine till this point ..
At the last line after it I need a way to make the code waits till the application is completely loaded instead of using `Application.Wait` method ..

Comment: How would you expect that to work exactly?   One way might be to use a loop to wait until a specific element is rendered on the page - have you considered that approach?

Comment: Yes I have used this trick before but doesn't work well for the web application .. sometimes work and sometimes throw an error .. so not stable

Comment: If it throws an error then you can catch the error and proceed...

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by catch the error and proceed ..!?

Comment: I mean like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait  I guess it would help your question if you showed the code you tried and described exactly what the problem was that you had when you tried that approach. If it's not working with Selenium then you could maybe try IE instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. I tried QHarr's code in the link you posted and worked fine for me.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.