# Selenium (VBA / CHROME) - Find element by id

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wonder why VBA cannot find element Id which is unique.
This is very simple but I want to know the reason why.

In other website, I can do `findelementbyid` or `css`.
[image]

I tried to find this element by using below code but it failed.
Do you have any idea?

```
bot.FindElementById("a_74").SendKeys "ht"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the FindElementById that fails? (i don't code in VBA so i had to take an example).
If so, since Explicit Wait are not available in VBA (i think) you could use a loop to retry the search certain times :

```
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
t = Timer
Do
    DoEvents
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = .FindElementById("a_74")
    On Error GoTo 0
If Timer - t = 10 Then Exit Do
Loop While ele Is Nothing
```

From :
[Selenium Webdriver (VBA): Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait)

Comment: Thank you. I tried with this code as well. but there was error with '21': TimeoutError. The driver failed to open the listening port ..-