# (Excel VBA selenium) How to reload a page if it is timeout? I have some codes

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, timeout, explicit

```
Set chkdata = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
chkdata.Get "http://example.com"
chkdata.Window.Maximize
chkdata.FindElementByName("ctl00$PublicMasterPage").WaitDisplayed.Click
```

Hi all, I have the above code which was working nice before but not now.
Go to example.com, wait couple of seconds, maximize the window of Chrome and click a particular button.
However, the server responding very slow recently causing VBA selenium message timeout and halt the program.

My questions:

1. How long did the function (.Get) to determine the timeout situation and trigger to halt the program in VBA selenium?
2. How can I set a timer for step 2? (Reload the webpage if it waits X sec)

Selenium Webdriver (VBA): Explicit Wait
[Selenium Webdriver (VBA): Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956889/selenium-webdriver-vba-explicit-wait)

I find a solution above called explicit wait. But if the webpage got fully loaded in 6 sec say for an example, will it still wait till the time limit (let's say time limit is 1 min) before the program goes to stpe 3?

I expect setting a wait timer like 30 sec, if the page got loaded before 30s, the program is able to move immediately but not wait for 30s. Thank you.

Comment: the .get() call will wait for the page to load.  The timeout period there is, by default, pretty long but varies by browser.  (I think it used to be like 5 minutes for Firefox) If it's getting stuck there, the only thing you can do is call .get() again after the timeout period.  (you can try/catch it)  You can set the page load timeout period for the get() call: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#pageLoadTimeout(java.time.Duration) It's an option of the webdriver.